# Ionic 5 / Angular 9: @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation, doesn't start()

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I can't figure out why this plugin doesn't work in my app: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation

My code: https://plnkr.co/edit/LAfbfU5edGhQmmkg?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

It runs startBackgroundGeolocation() but never enters ".subscribe", it doesn't even enter into ".then()" block in app.component.ts at line 54:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import {
  BackgroundGeolocation,
  BackgroundGeolocationConfig,
  BackgroundGeolocationResponse,
  BackgroundGeolocationEvents
} from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation/ngx';

import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  positionSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private dbRt: AngularFireDatabase,
    private backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.startBackgroundGeolocation();
    });
  }

  startBackgroundGeolocation() {
    const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 1,
      distanceFilter: 0,
      interval: 1000,
      fastestInterval: 1000,
      activitiesInterval: 1000,
      stopOnStillActivity: false,
      startForeground: true,
      startOnBoot: true,
      debug: true, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
      stopOnTerminate: false // enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
    };

    this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).then(() => {
      this.backgroundGeolocation
        .on(BackgroundGeolocationEvents.location)
        .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
          console.log(location);

          if (location.speed === undefined) {
            location.speed = 0;
          }

          this.dbRt.database
            .ref(`/gps/${this.authService.userprofile.value.uid}`)
            .push({
              date: moment.tz('Indian/Mauritius').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
              timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
              platform: 'background GPS !!!'
            })
            .then((res) => {
              // this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              // this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY
            });

          // IMPORTANT:  You must execute the finish method here to inform the native plugin that you're finished,
          // and the background-task may be completed.  You must do this regardless if your operations are successful or not.
          // IF YOU DON'T, ios will CRASH YOUR APP for spending too much time in the background.
        });
    });

    // start recording location
    this.backgroundGeolocation.start().then((state) => {
          console.log('state: ' + state);
    });
  }
}
```

It doesn't seem to even start backgroundGeolocation at line 84:

```
this.backgroundGeolocation.start().then((state) => {
     console.log('state: ' + state);
});
```

I'm using appflow to create the apk and tested it on a Samsung S8 / Android 7.0, it doesn't even prompt me to grant any access as it did for the regular geolocation. I would expect to get a backgroundGeolocation permission to allow, but nothing pops up.

When I try to implement the regular Geolocation plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation), everything works fine, I get the grant geolocation permission when I first launch the app, and I can save lat/lng to my DB.

Answer (score 0):

You have seted

> desiredAccuracy: 10

and to make it work you need to have new location 10m distance from old one.